# Ubuntu hangs on start, System halted, bad swap partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, encryption

After installing a new SSD, I formatted (using the Ubuntu Disk app) and perhaps I mess up the swap partition of my main SSD, which by the way is encrypted!

Now I cannot longer access the system. It hangs on the booting, right after I insert the initial password to decrypt the disk (password is the correct one).

- I've tried several things to fix this: Repair the boot that
  [generated this report](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wFbzwVSBb8/).
- Fix Ubuntu when it wont boot [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/196740/how-to-fix-an-ubuntu-system-when-it-wont-boot/)
- Start with live DVD and Re-install, is not possible! No matter what I choose, I always get the same error message in a black terminal:

  ```
  uncompression error
  -- System halted
  ```

It seems that I mess up the swap partition,
I'd like to fix it but don't really know what partition I need to fix and what are the steps.

I also unplugged all other drivers and cards that are not absolutely necessary besides swapping RAM modules.